# unwanted redefinition

Tags: c-preprocessor

I would like to define log levels in my code:

```
#define INFO 1
#define WARNING 2
#define ERROR 4
#define DEBUG 8
```

But in some other standard Microsoft libs ERROR already defined and looks like other words are also reserved. How to deal in such situation?

Comment: What do you want the end result to be in such situations? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft defines a lot of macros which get injected into your code whether you like them or not. So you better not repeat their error and avoid defining macros.

The best that you can do is to define *constants* instead of macros, and put them inside a namespace to avoid name clashes. For instance:

```
namespace Log
{
  const int Info = 1;
  const int Warning = 2;
  const int Error = 4;
  const int Debug = 8;
}
```

Then you would use them in your code as `Log::Info`, `Log::Error` and so on.

EDIT: As Tinctorius points out in a comment, you would probably be better off using an `enum` in this case:

```
enum LogLevel
{
  Info = 1;
  Warning = 2;
  Error = 4;
  Debug = 8;
}
```

In this case you don't need to prefix the values with the `enum` type name, just use variables of this type. For instance:

```
LogLevel level = Warning;
```

This has the advantage of offering type safety. You can also reuse the names for other `enum`s.

Comment: `enum` would be better here.

Comment: @Tinctorius Yes, for this purpose it would be better. I am updating my answer.

Comment: Another advantage it offers is that a `const int` might be treated as a global variable, depending on its use (`int *p = (int*)&Warning; *p = 0`). `const int`s are nothing more than `int`s with restricted access *through that name*, and an optimizer has to convince itself that the underlying storage is never changed before it may inline it.

Comment: Although compiling that results in a write to read-only memory for me ;)

Comment: @Tinctorius I think (too lazy to search the standard now) that compilers can assume that anything declared `const` is really `const`. If you later try to do some trick to un-const that, well, that's what you get :)

Comment: Looked it up. Turns out the behaviour of that snippet of code is undefined under [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) (according to 6.7.3 clause 5). In a footnote for clause 3, it also says: "The implementation may place a const object that is not volatile in a read-only region of storage. Moreover, the implementation need not allocate storage for such an object if its address is never used." So my explanation of `const` was wrong, but note that it's still essentially a global piece of data, rather than a purely compile-time entity.